# Haskell: Count infixes of a string

Tags: string, haskell, filter, count

I want to count, how often the String "egg" is in a given String.
I just know how to count chars

```
easter :: String -> Int
easter s = length $ filter (== 'e') s
```

Example: easter "eggabcdefgegggzueggeggegg" -> 5

Thank you in advance

Comment: is overlapping allowed? does "egegeg" have one "egeg" or two?

Comment: no one, i want to count every connected "egg"

Comment: well, how many "xox" in "xoxox" then?

Comment: I don't think he's asking for the generalized implementation.  Just one specialized to 'egg'.

Comment: I didn't  thought about this special case, it doesn't matter i think, with "egg" you don't have this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Extracting Sublists](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:10) section of the Data.List standard library.

You want to build a function that looks at each point in the String (remember `String` is a type alias for `[Char]`) to see if it starts "egg."

Here is how I might do it.

```
easter :: String -> Int
easter str = length $ filter (isPrefixOf "egg") (tails str)
```

Answer (score 3):

Without possibility of overlapping it's as easy as

```
> let s="eggabcdefgegggzueggeggegg" in sum [1 | i <- tails s, take 3 i == "egg"]

5
```

`tails` is in `Data.List`.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping in mind that a `String` is just a `[Char]`, pattern matching is simple.

```
easter :: String -> Int
easter [] = 0
easter ('e':'g':'g':rest) = 1 + easter rest
easter (x:xs) = easter xs
```

An empty string clearly has 0 occurrences of "egg".

If the string starts with "egg", there's at least 1 occurrence. Remove it, and check the remainder of the string.

If the string starts with anything else, remove the first letter and continue.

Answer (score 1):

Counting words can be quite easy. Just use a boyer moore implementation

```
import Data.Text.Internal.Search (indices)
import qualified Data.Text as T

easter :: String -> Int
easter = length . indices (T.pack "egg") . T.pack
```

Now the fun part is writing the algorithm yourself.  It's a great learning exercise and common in algorithm classes.  Try it out!  Don't bother to use Text the first time, just use String as you already have been and follow the wikipedia article.

Comment: Do you know, why it says: Module ‘Data.Text.Internal.Search’ does not export ‘indicies’ ?

Comment: Because it isn't `indicies` it is `indices` (note the `ie` vs just `e`).  I'll edit to fix that typo. EDIT:  I also imported Text qualified to avoid a name clash on `length`.